# Reading lines from a ram file

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to read data (skipping some lines up front) from a ram file, but function `ram_file:read_line/1` seems to be unimplemented:

```
Eshell V5.9.2  (abort with ^G)

1> Data = "first line
1> second_line".
"first line\nsecond_line"
2> {ok, File} = file:open(Data, [ram]).
{ok,{file_descriptor,ram_file,#Port<0.504>}}
3> file:read_line(File).
** exception error: undefined function ram_file:read_line/1
```

I tried opening the file with other modes specified: `raw`, `read` and `read_ahead`, but it returns `{error,badarg}`

I know I can read the data into a buffer and iterate over it, but is there another way to do this?

Comment: I've been thinking about creating an in-memory IO module for unit testing based on the documentation here: http://erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/io_protocol.html. You could certainly do that, although that's probably more work than necessary.

Comment: @macintux this sounds interesting, but as you wrote this would be too much work for now.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how one would open, write, read and close a RAM file.

```
main (IOdata) ->
    {ok, Fd} = file:open("bla", [ram,write,read,binary]),
    ok = file:write(Fd, IOdata),
    {ok, Str} = file:pread(Fd, 0, 8192),
    ok = file:close(Fd),
    Str.
```

The func you are looking for is [file:pread/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#pread-3)

Comment: I don't understand this line code `ok = file:write(Fd, IOdata),`, Could you explain it?

Comment: Well it is here so that we can `pread` something from the RAM file. It makes sure some IOdata gets written to Fd.

Comment: I know I can do that, the main problem is skipping some lines at the start of the file.

Comment: The third arg to [`file:pread/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#pread-3) is the number of bytes to read. To find the length of an entire in-memory file, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770144/find-length-of-elixir-erlang-in-memory-file/43770189

Answer (score 0):

`ram_file:read_line/1` seems to be not implemented in OTP. Only thing I could suggest is using `io:get_line/1` if you are dealing only with "ram data", or implementing `read_line` in `ram_file` module with use of `io:get_line/1`.

Comment: Sorry, tried that: `** exception error: no function clause matching io:request({file_descriptor,ram_file,#Port<0.504>},            {get_line,unicode,[]}) (io.erl, line 478)`

Comment: Yes; you are wright. I must mix up some things regarding `io:get_line/1`, and submit my answer little too soon (and based only on type spec :/). Regardless you should look into extend [`ram_file`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/kernel/src/ram_file.erl) module (or implement your own file handler based on it, just like @macintux suggested) if file handling is your case. If you are just trying to split char-list you cold look into `string:tokens/2`.

Comment: Be aware that the `:ram_file` module is currently undocumented in OTP so it is subject to change/deletion.